# How to plott an Interaction with categorical data (Example)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, statistics

What is my study about?
I let rank pictures (with in differences in Gender (m/f) and Postures (Open/Closed)) in Intelligence (Ranking from 1 to 4)

What's my aim:
I know I have an Interaction of Posture and Sex on Intelligence and I want to visualize it.

What's my problem?:

I thought I would just see 2 lines like the following picture:
[![a Plot like this would be my aim][1]][1]

So following questions occur to me:
Why are vertical lines there?

Why are there orange dots at every crossing of Int and Sex?

Why does the blue OpenPosture go from 4 to 4? This doenst make sense, that all open postures have the highest rank as ranking.

[![Picutre 1][2]][2]

I'm thankful for any advice or alternatives...

I base my code on
http://philippmasur.de/blog/2018/11/26/visualizing-interaction-effects/

My Code was:

```
##Prepare Data
x = ForkinDatenElefantReduced

##UV
#Small
Pos= factor(x$Pos)
Sex= factor(x$Sex)

contrasts(Pos) <- -1*contr.sum(2)
contrasts(Sex) <- -1*contr.sum(2)

##Fixed

Int = factor(x$Intelligence)
CoP = factor(x$`Commitement Patient`)

##Model

require(ordinal)
uwe2 <- clm(Int ~Pos +Sex, data = x)
print(summary(uwe2))



## Creating the plot
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(x, aes(x = Sex, 
              y = Int, 
              color = Pos)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Pos)) +
  geom_point() +

  labs(x = "Gender",
       color  = "Postures",
       y = "Int")
```

I wanted to add whiskers like Phillipmasur did, but it didn't work (following code is copied from his website, linked above:

```
 geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y_mean-1.96*y_se, 
                      ymax = y_mean+1.96*y_se),
                width = .1) +
  ylim(0, 17) +
  labs(x = "Factor A",
       color  = "Factor B",
       y = "Dependent Variable") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

As following you can see my data:

```
> x = ForkinDatenElefantReduced
> dput(x)
structure(list(No = c(31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 
41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 
57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 
73, 74, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 118, 
119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 
132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 
145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 
158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 75, 76, 77, 
78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 
94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 
108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 75, 76, 77, 
78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 
94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 
108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 
121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 
134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 
147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 
160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 
53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 
69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 
33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 
49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 
65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 
81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 
97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 
110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 
123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 
136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 
149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 
162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 
125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 
138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 
151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 
164, 165, 166, 167, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 
86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 
101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 
114, 115, 116, 117, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 
46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 
62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74), SetID = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Picid = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16), PicName = c("F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", 
"F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", 
"F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", 
"F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", 
"F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", 
"F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1A", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", 
"F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", 
"F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", 
"F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1B", "F1C", "F1C", 
"F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", 
"F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", 
"F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", 
"F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", 
"F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1C", 
"F1C", "F1C", "F1C", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", 
"F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", 
"F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", 
"F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", 
"F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", "F1D", 
"F1D", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", 
"F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", 
"F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", 
"F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", 
"F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2A", "F2B", 
"F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", 
"F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", 
"F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", 
"F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", 
"F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", 
"F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2B", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", 
"F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", 
"F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", 
"F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", 
"F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2C", 
"F2C", "F2C", "F2C", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", 
"F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", 
"F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", 
"F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "F2D", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", 
"M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", 
"M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", 
"M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", "M1A", 
"M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", 
"M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", 
"M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", 
"M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", 
"M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1B", "M1C", 
"M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", 
"M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", 
"M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", 
"M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", 
"M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1C", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", 
"M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", 
"M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", 
"M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", 
"M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", 
"M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", "M1D", 
"M1D", "M1D", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", 
"M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", 
"M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", 
"M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", 
"M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", 
"M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2A", "M2B", "M2B", 
"M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", 
"M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", 
"M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", 
"M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", 
"M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2B", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", 
"M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", 
"M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", 
"M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2C", "M2D", 
"M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", 
"M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", 
"M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", 
"M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", 
"M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D", "M2D"), Sex = c("F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M"), Pos = c("Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
"Open", "Open", "Open", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed"
), Intelligence = c(3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 
4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 
2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 
2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 
1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 
4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 
3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 
4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 
3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 
4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 
2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 
4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 
3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 
3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 
1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 
2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 
2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
3, 3, 3), `Commitement Patient` = c(3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 
3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 
1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 
3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 
4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 
4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 
4, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 
3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 
1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 
3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 
2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 
3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 
4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 
4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -668L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3MDa.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoDaA.png
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input can be used to test and verify possible solutions. We need the data in `ForkinDatenElefant` to run the code. Also double check the code is formatted correctly. There seem to be some misplaced parenthesis and partially commented lines

Comment: I edited the question and code. I added a data sample as link. Please reopen my question. Thank you

Comment: Data should not be posted at external sites. The link I provided on how to create a reproducible example shows how data should be included in the question itself. You need a more precise description of the problem than just "it doesn't work". What exactly do you want the picture to look like.

Comment: Okay I rewrote the question the question, deleted the link and added the data